# WordPress site breaks when www. is added to URL

Tags: wordpress

I was hoping someone could help me with a weird error I'm experiencing.

I've transferred a WordPress site using the [Duplicator plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) and now I'm experiencing a situation where when I visit the site without "www" it works fine, however when the www. is included I get this error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/*****/public_html/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/acf.php:1173) in /home/*****/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1167
```

The domain name also got transferred to our hosting platform so I think it could also be something to do with DNS records?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Please note that I can't share the URL for client privacy reasons. If you need any more specific information let me know and I'll try and source it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best way, but it works. I used an .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```